# How to fix problem alter table modify column commit not working

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, ddl

I try to modify a data type of column existing(LAST_RETRY_OPERATOR was TIMESTAMP(6)). It working with oracle sqldeveloper.

Here my request:

```
ALTER TABLE SIMBA_V2.GTPP01_LOT MODIFY (LAST_RETRY_OPERATOR VARCHAR2 (255));
ALTER TABLE SIMBA_V2.GTENT01_LOT MODIFY (LAST_RETRY_OPERATOR VARCHAR2 (255));
COMMIT;
```

I have some problem when i try to execute with sqlplus:
I had this message :

```
Table altered.
Table altered.
Commit complete.
```

But in the database not change.
How can i fix it?

---

I try to execute the request but nothing to change in the database after the command

LAST_RETRY_OPERATOR is still TIMESTAMP.

Comment: As SQLPlus did not show any errors, the ALTER statement were successful. What exactly is your question? Btw: the `commit` is useless.

Comment: Not the case(*non-changing data type*). Please connect to SIMBA_V2 (*if it's a DB user as we guessed*), and retry to issue your commands without qualifying with `SIMBA_V2`. Have a [look at](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0c78bc8b3ca17f665c78d5b9f54c6c62)

Comment: My question is SQLPLUS with he Alter statement successful but the DB is not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ALTER TABLE SIMBA_V2.GTPP01_LOT modify LAST_RETRY_OPERATOR VARCHAR2(255) not null;

commit;

ALTER TABLE SIMBA_V2.GTENT01_LOT modify LAST_RETRY_OPERATOR VARCHAR2 (255) not null;

commit;

After this issue this command to check

---

desc SIMBA_V2.GTPP01_LOT;

Comment: issuing `commit` after a DDL statement has no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Finally , Il found the problem.The request work well but sqlplus had some problem uncommited.